# Strange OutOfMemoryException and memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm facing really strange `OutOfMemoryException` problem. First of all, I don't have problem with loading big bitmaps. My problem is based on memory leaks. Application is quite common - few activities; one main activity with fragments replaced on view.

After a few minutes of using application, I get `OOME` because there is no more memory available.

I've made some investigation with MAT and two of my projects consists this kind of problem:

`Merged shortest paths to GC roots without weak references`

[image: First project memory leak]
[image: Second project memory leak]

Few `Bitmaps` or `BitmapShaders` are hold by "something". I'm using Android support library (`Fragments` etc.) and `Android-Universal-Image-Loader` library (loading images).

Image loading library is initialized this way in Application (in my opinion there is no problem):

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
   .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
   .build());
```

Thanks in advance for every advice.

Comment: I assume `this` is the current activity?

Comment: No, It's base application context (Application).